# How to give id names to <input> and selector values dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently looping through a list and appending that information as follows. I want to use the 'ID' information from that list and send that information to a url every time I press the 'Paid' button. This works currently when I hard code the selector as '#input1' and id value as identity[0].

This would not work if I were to have a second set of information with a new id and a new button that goes along with it cos during append, the 2nd button will also be of id input1.

Is there a way to dynamically give different id names to the button each time it loops, pair it up with the list id number and a way to give info to the selector depending on which button is pressed?

Or is there a better way to do this? Please advice. Thanks.

```
var identity = [];
var count = 0;

$.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/listunpaidbills/",function(data){
        //Loop for each element on the data
        $.each(data,function(elem){
            var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
            count++;
            identity.push(data[elem].id); 
            //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
            $("<h1/>",{
                text:data[elem].reference
            }).appendTo(wrap);   
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Account: "+ data[elem].account
            }).appendTo(wrap);        
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            $("<input type='submit' value='Paid' id='input1'/>",{
                text:"Paid"
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            wrap.appendTo('#unpaidList');             
        })//end of for each loop 
        $( "#unpaidList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    })

        $("#input1").click(function(){
          $.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/confirmbill/", {
                id: identity[0] 
                }, function(data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("error");
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your simplest solution would be to

add a class to your input to select it

add a data attribute to the same input to identify which identity[] index you want.

```
$("<input type='submit' value='Paid' id='input1'/>",{
     text:"Paid"
```

becomes

```
$("<input type='submit' value='Paid' />",{
     class:"myinput", 
     text:"Paid"
   }).appendTo(wrap)
   .data('identityindex',count)
```

and

```
    $("#input1").click(function(){
      $.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/confirmbill/", {
            id: identity[0]
```

becomes

```
    $(".myinput").click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var index = parseInt($this.data('identityindex')); 

      $.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/confirmbill/", {
            id: identity[index]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I check what this does? should I declare a separate variable for this?  data:{'identityindex':count},

Comment: Your code makes perfect sense but some how I am getting a validation error. The problem seems to lie on this line: id: identity[$this.data('identityindex')]

Comment: I think you likely have to convert the value to an int. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried adding an alert to see the value for index. It comes out as NaN. Seems the id number is not being registered

Comment: data:{'identityindex':count},this line of code is not working. the information is not being stored. the value returns as undefined.

Comment: I updated the answer to add the data attribute after it is appended to the DOM.

Comment: Also, I think the id on the input tag is likely invalid html as the code will make multiple inputs with the same id. I removed that also in the example.

Answer (score 0):

While you appending button with Json response.
if you want to make id dynamic then on that time you have to bind **click** function to that button try:

```
$.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/listunpaidbills/",function(data){
        //Loop for each element on the data
        $.each(data,function(elem){
            //your code 
            var dynamicId = "input2";//local variable of dynamic button

            $("<input type='submit' value='Paid' id='"+dynamicId+"'/>",{
                text:"Paid"
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            wrap.appendTo('#unpaidList');

//binding click event to created button

$("#input1").bind('click',function(){
          $.getJSON("http://website.com/public/user/confirmbill/", {
                id: identity[0] 
                }, function(data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("error");
            })
        });



        })//end of for each loop 
        $( "#unpaidList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    })
```